# Substituting a value in a list in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing some code to replace with 'X' all values in a square matrix which are greater than the values adjacent to it (above, below, left and right). But I'm getting a ValueError when I try to execute it.

Here's my code:

```
n = int(raw_input().strip())
grid = []
grid_i = 0
for grid_i in xrange(n):
    grid_t = list(raw_input().strip())
    grid.append(grid_t)

for x in xrange(1, n-1):
    for y in xrange(1, n-1):
        if (int(grid[x][y]) > int(grid[x-1][y]) and int(grid[x][y]) > int(grid[x+1][y]) and int(grid[x][y]) > int(grid[x][y+1]) and int(grid[x][y] > int(grid[x][y-1]))):
            grid[x][y] = "X"

print grid
```

Here's my traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 24, in <module>
    if (int(grid[x][y]) > int(grid[x-1][y]) and int(grid[x][y]) > int(grid[x+1][y]) and int(grid[x][y]) > int(grid[x][y+1]) and int(grid[x][y] > int(grid[x][y-1]))):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'X'
```

I understand that the error means I'm trying to apply the `int` function on a string in the `if` statement, but I can't think why the same works here:

http://www.martinkysel.com/hackerrank-cavity-map-solution/

The above site also shows the `int` function being applied on the list values. If there's a better code that can do the task, please do tell.

Comment: Because he has `arr[idx_tb-1][idx_lr] != 'X' and` at the beginning.

Comment: And far better is `grid_t = [int(i) for i in raw.input().strip().split()]` which allows you to drop four noisy and repetitive `int` conversions below.

Comment: @zondo - yes, i saw that, but i couldn't understand what benefit that has

Comment: It only solves your problem ;).  He puts that there because `'X'` is not a valid integer.  If that code is at the beginning and the value is `'X'`, the `if` statement will not execute and the `int(...)` will not even be evaluated.  There won't be any errors.

Comment: @zondo - Okay, thanks. Got it ! :)

Comment: @zondo - I needed another help. I'm taking the inputs as a list and appending it to the grid. But I want to take them as strings instead. I know Python strings are immutable, so how would I go about assigning 'X'?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  If you want to append a string instead of a list to `grid`, take out the `list(` at the beginning and `)` at the end of `grid_t = list(raw_input().strip())`.

Comment: I meant something like `grid_t = str(raw_input().strip())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it..

```
n = int(raw_input().strip())
grid = []
for grid_i in xrange(n):
    grid+= raw_input().split()

a=[grid[0]]
for x in xrange(1, n-1):
    s=''
    s+=grid[x][0]
    for y in xrange(1, n-1):        
        if(int(grid[x][y]) > int(grid[x-1][y]) and int(grid[x][y]) > int(grid[x+1][y]) and int(grid[x][y]) > int(grid[x][y+1]) and int(grid[x][y] > int(grid[x][y-1]))):
            s+= "X"
        else:
            s+=grid[x][y]
    s+=grid[x][n-1]    
    a.append(s)
a.append(grid[n-1])

print a
```